# Modular application architecture and Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I'm developing a .Net desktop app that interacts with scientific instruments. There are a number of variations of this instrument, each with different features, components, etc, so I've come up with a plugin/modular architecture where a "module assembly" contains all of the necessary business logic, UI, etc. to interact with that hardware component/feature.

Currently I have one solution that contains everything - the "core" application project, common libraries, plus the "module" projects. The idea is that we install the whole lot to a customer site (rather than cherry-picking which DLLs they need), and "activate" the relevant modules using a config file that contains a list of required modules.

The main application project loads the modules using Castle Windsor, using an AssemblyFilter and a custom InstallerFactory. It searches each module assembly looking for a class implementing `IWindsorInstaller` *and* decorated with a particular custom attribute (which has a property containing the module name). The module's installer will only be run if the attribute's module name is one of those requested. These installer classes are responsible for registering everything needed by that module with Windsor (business logic, views, view models, etc.).

This solution works fine in my proof of concept, however I can see a scenario where two or more modules are functionally very similar, and will therefore need to share common code. Let's say I have projects "ModuleA" and "ModuleB", and their Windsor installers registers the same `IFooService` class in project "ClassLibraryX". The app will fall over because IFooService has been reigstered twice, and Windsor won't know which one to resolve when requested by a constructor.

What's the best way to handle this? Thoughts so far:-

- Find out if a particular component has already been registered with Windsor. This feels hacky (if possible at all)
- Register components using a name, but how do I request a named instance with constructor injection?
- In each module project create a new interface, such as `public interface IModuleAFooService : IFooService`, and register/use this throughout the project (rather than `IFooService`).

Any thoughts?

**Edit**: in fact Windsor won't fall over when it tries to resolve `IFooService`. It will fall over when the second module attempts to register the same interface/concrete implementation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, you have a couple options.  I think you have two main issues.  The first is that you are installing the shared interface twice (or more than that).  The second is that you could have two different versions of the shared interface.

For the first issue, I would separate out the shared interfaces into their own assembly.  Inside that assembly, I would have an installer that is scoped to that assembly.  Then, you can tell Windsor to install that shared component and it knows how to wire itself up.

For the second issue, you have two options (as I see it).  First option is that you keep your shared components backwards compatible.  Second option is to isolate you runtime (through app domains or processes).

Comment: I also thought about having an installer in the "shared" assembly, but I guess that would mean registering these shared components regardless of whether or not any of the dependent modules have been "activated". Perhaps I'm just making a mountain out of a mole hill, and the unnecessary registration (which happens at startup) has minimal overhead.

Comment: Yes, I think the registration of components that are available has very little overhead.  I would think of like this:  You are activating core components that could be used, but each module will take care of making sure that it is active before executing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not provide some meta-data for the plugin, i.e give each plugin implementation a name attribute which can be used by windsor to identify which of the implementations you want?

I have not used Castle too much recently but I am sure it did have the notion of named Bindings/Registrations, so you could use that as a way to distinguish things, if that is not going to be possible and there is no other meta data you can think of using which would make it less ambiguous for Windsor, then I would just opt with your 3rd option.

Having just read your 2nd option again (after writing the above) that seems the best option, I cannot remember EXACT syntax but in most DI frameworks you do something like:

```
var instance = Get<IMyInterface>("Named This");
```

There will be loads of syntax examples on their documentation somewhere, but you will need to know the name on both the Windsor side to register it AND on the client side to request it.

Comment: The problem is that my app might load two plugins, both requiring the same implementation. Each plugin is responsible for registering its dependencies with Windsor, and wouldn't know if another plugin has already registered the same implementation, resulting in the same implementation being registered twice, causing Windsor to fall over. I know you can register the same implementation under different names, but then I'm not sure how you tell Windsor which one you want, when using constructor injection.

Comment: OH I am with you, there seems to be one problem you have overlooked then if this is the case. If you have 2 plugins which both have the implementation of the interface you need, lets say `ZipPlugin` and `RarPlugin` and they both share an implementation you need called `CompressedFile : ICompressedFile` you may not have the same version of that implementation, if one plugin is version 1.0 and the other is 2.1 you may have a newer version in one of the plugins which may or may not be compatible, so the version of each plugin and their shared classes is something you may need to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Named instances are ok. You can define dependency on concrete named service via `DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("paramName", "serviceName"))` method in fluent configuration.